# How to migrate documents from Sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint online programatically using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

I want to migrate documents from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint online  using C# code.

Comment: You should post some code, also what did you try, what didn't work,etc...
If you just ask without code, your question will be deleted probably.

Comment: One file? Thousands of files? A single list of files or multiple sites, libraries and folders? Why write code? You may want to look at the many migration tools available, some of which are free. Here is Microsoft's free one, and it does work with 2010: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint client object model (CSOM) to read data from SharePoint on premise and write it to SharePoint Online.

Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code